# Error when passing urllib.urlopen result to json.load

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, twitter, urllib

I'm new to python but would like to use urllib to download tweets, I'm following a tutorial instructions but get the same error every time, I print:

```
import urllib
import json
response = urllib.urlopen("https://twitter.com/search?q=Microsoft&src=tyah")
print json.load(response)
```

But everytime I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\print.py", line 4, in <module>
    print json.load(response)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: It would make more sense to copy and paste the traceback as text instead of attaching a screenshot. Also, why do you expect a JSON object in the response? Have you checked its contents?

Comment: 1- I tried the urllib.urlopen alone (without json command) but it wouldn't give results 2- how can I know whether the content it json or not?

Comment: Well, the response object is a lot like a file object. You can `read` from it. Try `print response.read()` and you'll see it's not JSON.

Comment: thanks for that, but I don't even get results when I print 
response = urllib.urlopen("https://twitter.com/search?q=Microsoft&src=tyah"), so there is no response object to read

Comment: What do you mean "get results"? The code is probably executed, it just doesn't print anything.

Comment: I'm sorry I bothered you, but I already used the (print command ) response = urllib.urlopen("https://twitter.com/search?q=Microsoft&src=tyah")
print reponse but all I get is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\print.py", line 4, in <module>
    print reponse
NameError: name 'reponse' is not defined

Comment: You have a typo, it's `response`, not `reponse`.

Comment: I get this error addinfourl at 55392904L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0000000002ED1B88.  when I print the result of urllib, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, the answer is: nothing is wrong with your code, per se.

The problem is that when `json.load` looks at `response`, it does not find JSON in there - it is finding HTML.

You need to pass a file-like object containing JSON into the `json.load` function, or it will raise the exception you see here.

To get JSON from Twitter, you need to call a URL that gives a JSON response. I can tell you now, that none of the Web interface URLs do this directly. You should use the Twitter API.

However, purely for sake of demonstration, if you deconstruct the page at the URL you are calling now, you will find that to load the tweet data, the page makes the following request:

https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?q=Microsoft&src=tyah&composed_count=0&include_available_features=1&include_entities=1

And this URL does return JSON in response, which would work just fine with your current code.

Of course, I'm pretty sure doing so violates some sort of Twitter TOS, so if you do this there are all sorts of potential negative repercussions to consider. Plus it's just not good sportsmanship. :)

Comment: thank you for that, but if I use the normal URL(html response) like https://twitter.com/search?q=Microsoft&src=tyah, what is the correct command to do that? will we still use urllib.urlopen? and how to print the result out? if I do so I get that error all the time Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\print.py", line 4, in <module>
    print reponse
NameError: name 'reponse' is not defined,

Comment: If you just want to output the html?

Comment: All I want is follow specific steps to pull tweets then save it, whether that using urllib or any other module, can you please recommend the proper commands and sequence to accomplish that!